# Regex for everything except certain matches

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a redirect regex script that will forward the user onto another domain with the path intact, except when the path matches something specific.

i.e.

`http://www.a.com/anything/foo/bar -> http:www.b.com/anything/foo/bar`

but if the path starts with something special, then don't redirect:

`http://www.a.com/special/1/2/3 -> no redirect`

My redirect app works like this: I put entries in line by line (this works fine):

```
"^/(?P<path>[-\w]+)/(?P<foo>[-\w]+)/(?P<bar>[-\w]+)/$","%(path)s/%(bar)s/%(foo)s/"
"^/(?P<path>.*)$","http://www.b.com/%(path)s"
```

So something like this (doesn't work):

`"^/(?P<path>!(special).*)$","http://www.b.com/%(path)s"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a negative lookahead:

```
"^/(?P<path>(?!special/).*)$","http://www.b.com/%(path)s"
```

The `(?!...)` syntax means:

> `(?!...)`
>   Matches if `...` doesn’t match next. This is a negative lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?!Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s not followed by `'Asimov'`.

so the expression matches if the path starts with `/` but is *not* followed by `special/`.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"^/(?P<path>(?!special/).*)$", '/special/path') is None
True
>>> re.search(r"^/(?P<path>(?!special/).*)$", '/not-so-special/path').groupdict()
{'path': 'not-so-special/path'}
```

Comment: Ah - I was missing the ? before the ! - getting confused with the initial ? for the named match.. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`http://www.a.com/(?!special).*` will match anything which starts with `http://www.a.com/` but not `http://www.a.com/special`.